# C++ casting question (structs)

Tags: c++, casting, struct

In my C++ application I have the definition:

```
struct socksddr_storage ss;
struct sockaddr *sa;
```

what is the different between the following:

```
sa = (struct sockaddr *)&ss;
```

and

```
sa = (sockaddr *)&ss;
```

???

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in C++ as the `struct` keyword is optional.  In C, the second form is not legal.

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference between the two.  The typecast with the struct keyword present harkens back to the days of C, where the type of a struct included the keyword "struct" and is why the phrase "typedef struct" became popular.  C++ eliminated the need for this keyword in this context, but kept the syntax alive for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `(struct sockaddr*)` is a valid cast in both C and C++, where is `(sockaddr*)` is valid in C++ but not in C. Both casts achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

As others already said, you don't need to write the `struct` prefix in c++ as the compiler is able to determine the correct type by the name only. But I suggest to use reinterpret_cast in this situation, as the c style cast is the big-hammer cast which casts types and const specifiers in one go.

```
struct socksddr_storage ss;
const struct socksddr_storage ss2;
struct sockaddr *sa;

sa = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr *>(&ss); // Works like the C Cast
sa = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr *>(&ss2); // Fails, because ss2 is a constant,
 // but sa is a pointer to a no const memory location. The C cast will allow
 // this assignment, but this can lead to runtime errors since the linker
 // can place ss2 into read-only memory.
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say definite thing as I don't know your actual context, but if you
see an error when you write `(sockaddr*)` and don't when `(struct sockaddr*)`,
my answer may apply.
`struct sockaddr` in `(struct sockaddr*)` is an elaborated type specifier.
Sometimes this is needed.
For example,

```
void f( void* p )
{
  int stat( char const*, struct stat* );
  struct stat *a = (struct stat*) p; // cannot omit this struct
}
```